# GROUP_CONCAT in elasticsearch

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

I have following query in MySQL,

`SELECT service, COUNT(*) as count, MAX(timestamp) as ts, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as id_list FROM logs GROUP_BY service ORDER BY ts DESC`

Can anyone tell me how to write the same query in elasticsearch?

`type` and `service` are a string.

Basically, I want to group by a field and get all the ids in the field as an array within the bucket.

Comment: could you put sample structure of your document

Comment: you might need to use aggregation to achieve this